# How do template languages/engines like DTL and Jinja express and manage the relationships between various template files?

Tags: python, django, jinja2, templating, templating-engine

I'm specifically using Django and Jinja2. This is my first foray into using templates without the help of a CMS to pick which ones and put them all together.

For some reason, I can't seem to comprehend how a bunch of pieces fit together.

I feel comfortable with these concepts:

- A template engine processes a template and a model to produce a useful result.
- A template file describes how model data should be fitted into it to produce that result.
- An application developer programmatically interacts with the engine and template objects which represent template file. The programmer is responsible for selecting a template file, providing the data, and handing it all to the engine. And then doing something with useful result the engine gives back.

But what I'm struggling with is this:

- Templates files can be written to inherit from each other, promoting DRY.
- Templates files contain information about their inheritance.

And now I fall down.

1. How does that work? Where in the system is this relationship used?
2. If I'm passing a base template to the engine, how does the engine know which child templates should be used?
3. If I'm passing a child template to the engine, okay, that template includes information about the template it extends, but what if the parent template needs more than that one child template?

I get the sense that I've got a faulty, big-picture understanding. Perhaps I am not understanding which responsibilities belong the template and which to the application?

Thanks very much!

**EDIT:**

I guess my first attempt at articulating my problem didn't work. Here's another shot:

[image: Some templates]

Figure 1 shows some templates I have (hypothetically). There's a base template, a header template, and two of each of a body, sidebar, and footer template.

There is a tree of inheritance. Each template specifies (if possible in my understanding) which template it extends.

And here lies the problem. Consider just the body and footer templates. They extend the base. But in my understanding, I can only choose one of these for rendering. If I choose one of the bodies, then I can't choose which footer I want. If I choose one of the footers, then I can't choose which body I want. If I want to be able to choose both body and footer, in my understanding, I must write four templates, one for each combination. Surely this can't be how it works?

Then we have the sidebars. Supposing I go ahead and make those four templates. Which of the four, then, should my sidebars extend? If I want to be able to choose either sidebar for all four layouts, then I must now create eight templates! Figure 2 shows the different combinations.

In an actual project (not just a personal project like the one I'm working on), I would expect to have more than just these things to deal with. Besides the different layouts already described, I would need different blocks in the sidebars, different layouts depending on whether the user is logged in or not, all sorts of stuff. I can easily imagine needing to write hundreds of templates to cover all possibilities.

If this is really how template systems work, then what should I be using instead?

Answer (score 0):

But these are not supported workflows. The only case that makes sense is a child extending a parent, and the child being sent to the template engine.

Any template can also include other templates directly, but that is not part of the inheritance chain.

Comment: Ah, a chain. So I explicitly can't use a tree of templates to build a page? I've been assuming that I'm supposed to be able to specify a tree structure in the templates.

So if I want that tree structure, I should build into my application's view logic?